# Highcharts: how to handle touch events via plotOptions.series.events

Tags: javascript, highcharts

On a Highcharts bar chart, when the user clicks one of the bars, additional data is loaded elsewhere on the page via the `loadDetails` function.

`loadDetails` is specified as a click callback function for a chart via `plotOptions.series.events`:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    defaultSeriesType: 'bar',
    ...
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            events: {
                click: loadDetails
            }
        }
    },
    ...

});

function loadDetails() {
    ...
}
```

The problem is I need to call the same callback function for a `touchstart` event on mobile devices.

There doesn't seem to be any obvious way of adding a touch event handler via the Highcharts API as far as I could tell: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.events.

Has anyone got any idea how to add callback functions for touch events, or trigger the click callback function from a touch event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, something like this is not supported, I advice you to create idea [here](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general).

The only workaround which comes to my mind is use [Element.on](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Element.on%28%29) function to add custom events to elements which exists on a chart. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/269/

```
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        events: {
            load: function(){
                var chart = this,
                    path = chart.series[0].tracker;

                path.on('click', function() {
                   alert("click");; 
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm looking into your suggested workaround, and can get a touchstart event hooked up via path.element.addEventListener - using path.on('touchstart') didn't seem to work - but then I don't seem to have access to event.point in the event handling function.

Comment: Why would you expect to have event.point? You are adding event to SVG element so you need to pass your point separately. Still I advice to use .on() - because it for sure will work in IE < 9.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't expecting to have event.point, but the existing callback function that's fired for the click event uses it. And fortunately IE < 9 isn't supported for what I'm working on.

Comment: Ah, okay. Good luck then with addEventListener!

Answer (score 0):

This works. I was trying to get Highcharts to work with Apple Pencil. I used code above but included markerGroup (along with tracker) so event triggers when user click on points along with lines of a series. I use ‘touchstart’ event to trap apple pencil click. See below.

```
chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        events: {
            load: function(){
                var chart = this,
                    path = chart.series[0].tracker;
                    path2 = chart.series[0].markerGroup;
            path.on('touchstart', function() {
               alert(“touch");
            });
            path2.on('touchstart'), function() {
               alert(“touch 2”);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work because there are a few syntax errors. Here is correct example which should works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/3awumjeg/