# Extracting chart coordinates from touch events for custom HighCharts interaction

Tags: highcharts

I am having some issues working with Touch events in HighCharts.  I am able to receive the events, but I haven't been able to figure out how to translate the coordinates given to chart coordinates.  For mouse events, I can use the following to retrieve the chart X value:

```
chart.xAxis[0].toValue(e.offsetX)
```

However, touch events have no `offsetX`.  For clicks, there is also `e.originalEvent.chartX`, which seems to be identical to `e.offsetX`, but again it is missing for touch events.  By inspecting the touch event I can find clientX, screenX, and pageX, but `axis.toValue` does not return the correct chart X for any of these values.

[touch event support in highchart for iphone/ipads or any touchable devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22502005/touch-event-support-in-highchart-for-iphone-ipads-or-any-touchable-devices)
and
[Highcharts: how to handle touch events via plotOptions.series.events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17320872/highcharts-how-to-handle-touch-events-via-plotoptions-series-events)
both mention using a "tracker" object to call `normalizeMouseEvent`, but I can't seem to find it in the API reference or by inspecting the relevant objects.

How can I extract the correct X and Y chart values from a touch event?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract that from changedTouches object.

```
e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].pageX
e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].pageY
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to extract the equivalent of event.offsetX that I am using for mouse events, I ended up using the following code:

```
function accumulate_offset(next_container) {
  offset = 0;
  while (next_container != null) {
    offset += next_container.offsetLeft;
    next_container = next_container.offsetParent;
  }
  return offset;
}

// then in handler
if (e.type.slice(0,5) == 'mouse') {
  xVal = e.offsetX;
} else {
  xVal = e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].pageX - accumulate_offset(e.currentTarget);
}
x = axis.toValue(xVal);
```

Hopefully this is helpful to someone.